# Can´t assign query result to a python variable

Tags: python, mysql, query-string, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I have this query:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxx',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='xxxx')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = ("SELECT app_id FROM op_ids")
cursor.execute(query)
LATCH_APP_ID=cursor.fetchall()


cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

The value of app_id on the database is **ybDWvzU4iijnqqX8xAxx** but when I run the python script , it returns **[(u'ybDWvzU4iijnqqX8xAxx',)]**, so I can't use it in other method because I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

If a use a variable like this:

```
LATCH_APP_ID = "ybDWvzU4iijnqqX8xAxx"
```

The script runs OK

Can anybody help me?

Comment: This value `[(u'ybDWvzU4iijnqqX8xAxx',)]` seems to be a list with one entry which is a tuple, that's why you get the error about concatenating a string and a list. Try to use `LATCH_APP_ID[0]` or even `LATCH_APP_ID[0][0]`(if my guess is correct this should be working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `cursor.fetchall()` has returned:

```
[(u'ybDWvzU4iijnqqX8xAxx',)]
```

So you only need to extract the string from with in the structures:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()

t = result[0]        # fetch the tuple from the first item in the list

LATCH_APP_ID = t[0]  # fetch the string from the first (only) item in the tuple
```